# Changing default base URL of Sitecore ServiceApiController, Is it possible?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

when we implement `SitecoreApiController`, for each action method we make using `Sitecore.Services.Core.ServicesController("namespace")` attribute, we get a url like this:

```
/sitecore/api/ssc/{namespace}/{controller}/{id}/{action}
```

I wonder if we could change this default pattern, somehow in config files. I particularly interested in `/sitecore/api/` part, because sometimes in the sense of security concerns, certain clients don't like to reveal that much about CMS platform behind the scene. Sometimes they even ask us to hide anything in HTTP header that tells about Microsoft ASP.NET explicitly.

Is this possible here?

**Edit**

[this link](http://laubplusco.net/implementing-webapi-service-using-servicesapicontroller-sitecore-8/) shows a way to customize it using pipelines but I wonder if we could change the base url just through config files without needing a custom pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at it, and I think I found out how - although I haven't tested it.

It looks for a setting named `Sitecore.Services.RouteBase` and if it can't find it, it uses `sitecore/api/ssc/` as the default value.

You should be able to change it with a config patch like this in the `App_Config/Include` folder:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Sitecore.Services.RouteBase" value="custom/api/" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what I was looking for. However I tried this just now and neither of default or custom URL is working. both return 404 error. Perhaps I can dig into the relevant object but in which dll or class this logic has been set?

Comment: `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.DefaultRouteMapper` sets up the routes. `RouteBase` is set in `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Configuration.ServicesSettingsConfigurationProvider`. The settings are defined in `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Globals`. These exist in the `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.dll` and `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.dll`.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking into these dlls right now and you're right. I can change "api" or "ssc" and still it works. However when I change the word "sitecore" in "sitecore/api/ssc/" I guess the request doesn't reach to these dlls and stops somewhere else; as if some other codes which bypass the process to service api are sensitive to "sitecore" as a constant. I checked "IgnoreUrlPrefixes" in web.config but didn't find any clue. I am not sure if this is a bug or I something is messed up in my project particularly.